# error @ sk_prot_alloc+0x9a/0x150 in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, debugging, linux-kernel, kmalloc

I'm debugging a module kernel I've written, and I get the following stack trace.

```
   37.700861] RIP: 0010:__kmalloc+0x9e/0x270
[   37.700864] Code: 7f 01 00 00 4d 8b 01 65 49 8b 50 08 65 4c 03 05 30 7d b6 6e 4d 8b 20 4d 85 e4 0f 84 8d 01 00 00 41 8b 41 20 49 8b 39 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 49 33 99 70 01 00 00 48 89 c1 48 0f c9 4c 89 e0 48 31 cb
[   37.700865] RSP: 0018:ffffabf80034fd60 EFLAGS: 00010286
[   37.700868] RAX: bb254e11a355074e RBX: 0000000000000dc0 RCX: 0000000000000000
[   37.700869] RDX: 0000000000001297 RSI: 0000000000000dc0 RDI: 000000000002f180
[   37.700871] RBP: ffffabf80034fd90 R08: ffffa09bfda2f180 R09: ffffa09bfd402540
[   37.700872] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: bb254e11a355074e
[   37.700874] R13: 0000000000000dc0 R14: 0000000000000440 R15: ffffa09bfd402540
[   37.700876] FS:  00007fe09707bc80(0000) GS:ffffa09bfda00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   37.700877] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   37.700879] CR2: 00007ffd5f377870 CR3: 0000000077ea6006 CR4: 00000000000606f0
[   37.700883] Call Trace:
[   37.700888]  ? sk_prot_alloc+0x9a/0x150
[   37.700891]  sk_prot_alloc+0x9a/0x150
[   37.700894]  sk_alloc+0x31/0x250
[   37.700897]  ? do_set_master+0xb0/0xb0
[   37.700900]  __netlink_create+0x37/0xc0
[   37.700902]  netlink_create+0x11b/0x250
[   37.700906]  __sock_create+0xe0/0x200
[   37.700908]  __sys_socket+0x5a/0xf0
[   37.700911]  ? schedule+0x33/0xa0
[   37.700913]  __x64_sys_socket+0x1a/0x20
[   37.700917]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
[   37.700919]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[   37.700921] RIP: 0033:0x7fe096335d57
```

does anyone know how do I translate this code the error in my code? maybe in clion?

Comment: Please, clarify question. Do you want to know why you get this stack trace?

Comment: I assume it caused because something that is related to memory allocation. I would like to see in my code where it has happened.

Comment: `entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe` this is where you came in from userspace. No idea what userspace function uses this syscall.

Comment: This looks like a simple `socket` syscall [which will protect itself from _any_ bad userspace parameters]. So, how does your kernel module fit in [and/or corrupt things]? There are no foreign [i.e. from _your_ module] symbols on the stack traceback. I think you need to _edit_ your question and post the [relevant] module code in a code block. Along with the userspace code that invokes this. At a guess, since the TB doesn't have your symbols, the corruption is done _prior_ to this point, but is only detected later. Also, a description of what your module does [and _why_]

Comment: I'm currently write a driver which uses primarily write and read. can you spot where the error has happen in my module?

Comment: _can you spot where the error has happen in my module?_ Not unless you post it (along with the other info) as I mentioned in my previous comment.